# Dynamic view of anonymous type missing member issue - MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dynamic, anonymous-types

I have an MVC3 site that I've setup for testing another site - most of it has been quick and dirty, and so I've not gone to town creating model and view model types for all the views - only where input is requried from the user.

Okay so I have a controller method that projects a Linq sequence and sets it into `ViewBag`.

```
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i=> new { Value = i });
```

In my view (Razor C#) I then want to read this - quite simple:

```
@foreach(dynamic item in ViewBag.SomeData)
{
  @:Number: @item.i
}
```

Except, of course, I get a `RuntimeBinderException` because the anonymous type created in the controller is internal to the web project's output assembly and the actual Razor code here will be running in a different assembly generated by the build manager so, all in all **DENIED!**

Obviously a 'proper' model type would solve the issue - but let's say I simply don't want to do that because that's my prerogative(!) - how best to keep the code to a minimum and retain the dynamic-ness here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I've done (and I stress this only really addresses the issue adequately for anonymous types); lifting the members out and pushing them into an `ExpandoObject`.

My initial change was to make the projection a multi-statement that returns an `ExpandoObject`:

```
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i=> {
  var toReturn = new ExpandoObject();
  toReturn.Value = i;
  return toReturn;
});
```

Which is almost as short as the anonymous type just not as clean.

But then I wondered if I could grab the publicly readable members out of the anonymous type (the type is internal, but the properties it generates are public):

```
public static class SO7429957
{
  public static dynamic ToSafeDynamic(this object obj)
  {
    //would be nice to restrict to anonymous types - but alas no.
    IDictionary<string, object> toReturn = new ExpandoObject();
  
    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties(
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Where(p => p.CanRead)) // watch out for types with indexers 
    {
      toReturn[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
    }

    return toReturn;
  }
}
```

Which means I can then use my original code - but with a little extension method call tagged on the end:

```
ViewBag.SomeData=Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i=> new { Value = i }.ToSafeDynamic());
```

It's **not** efficient, and it should definitely **not** be used for serious production code. But it's a good time saver.

Comment: Nice decision to use ExpandoObject - had forgotten about that as an option.

Comment: @Jon - thanks!  Let's face it though, it's a type that goes against almost all our previous C# concepts and so easy to forget.  Oh btw - C# In Depth Second Edition rocks.

Comment: My excuse is that I very rarely do *anything* with dynamic. Glad to hear you like the book :)

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously a 'proper' model type would solve the issue - but let's say
>   I simply don't want to do that because that's my prerogative(!)

You cannot have such prerogative. Sorry, there is absolutely no excuse for this :-) Not to mention that what you are trying to achieve is impossible because dynamic types are internal to the declaring assembly. Razor views are compiled into a separate dynamic assembly at runtime by the ASP.NET engine.

So back to the topic: never pass anonymous objects as models to views. Always define use view models. Like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new MyViewModel { Value = i });
    return View(model);
}
```

and then use a strongly typed view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and inside the corresponding display template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection so that you don't have to write any loops in your views (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@:Number: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value)
```

Things that we have improved from the initial version:

- We have strongly typed views with Intellisense (and if you activate compilation for views even compile time safety)
- Usage of strongly typed view models adapted to the specific requirements of your views.
- Getting rid of ViewBag/ViewData which imply weak typing
- Usage of display templates which avoid you writing ugly loops in your views => you rely on conventions and the framework does the rest

Comment: Believe me the MVC3 site that this is testing does indeed follow all of these principles; but I have to say if you're knocking up test apps for scenarios where people want to interactively test your site (it's a webservice-initiated thing) then I think a more rapid-prototyping approach is perfectly reasonable; and anyway I can make it my prerogative if I want to (ad infinitum)!

Comment: @Andras Zoltan, to achieve this you will have to write sooo much plumbing code to fight against the fact that the compiler generates dynamic types as internal that at the end of the day you would have wasted much of your precious time in doing some hacks instead of focusing of the implementation. Use Scaffolding if you want to do quick mockups.

Comment: 4 statements of an extension method did it.  I don't disagree with your points at all; but I see no reason to be bound to every last bit of best practise (aimed at achieving maintainable and efficient professional end-products) for something that is ultimately an ancillary 'tool for testing'.  I can develop it quickly and I can add and remove information from my views easily without having to worry about type management.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ToSafeDynamic` is a good solution. But I'd like to share some other options using the open source `ImpromptuInterface` (in nuget) that would work well in this situation.

One option, being a DynamicObject based proxy, [ImpromptuGet](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageDynamic#ImpromptuGet) which will just forward calls to the annonymous type, similar to using dynamic (it uses the same api's except it sets the context to the anonymous type's self so the `internal` access doesn't matter).

```
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10)
                           .Select(i => ImpromptuGet.Create(new { Value = i }));
```

This option doesn't look as clean as ToSafeDynamic, but it has a small distinction in that it is only calling the properties when they are used, rather than copying all the data upfront.

However, a better solution from `ImpromptuInterface` is it's [quick syntax](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBuilder) for creating prototype dynamic objects.

```
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i => Build.NewObject(Value:i));
```

that will create an expando-like object, but you also have the option to create literal `ExpandoObject`s (which in my testing offer the same performance on getters as POCO objects cast to dynamic).

```
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10)
                           .Select(i => Build<ExpandoObject>.NewObject(Value:i));
```

Also the creation setup portion can be stored in a temporary variable or fields to shorten the lambda even more.

```
var Expando =Build<ExpandoObject>.NewObject;
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i => Expando(Value:i));
```

Comment: +1 That is some cool stuff there; hadn't heard of this; I was thinking when I came up against this problem that if C# supported initializers on a dynamic such as ExpandoObject then the problem would be easily solved; using named parameters is a clever way to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just going for pure quick'n'dirty, you can always use Tuples in situations like this.

```
ViewBag.SomeData = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i=> new Tuple<int>(i);
```

-

```
@foreach(dynamic item in ViewBag.SomeData)
{
    @:Number: @item.Item1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the name of the assembly generated by the build manager? If so, you should be able to apply `InternalsVisibleTo` in the controller assembly, and it will all work fine.

EDIT: One possible solution: create a public type extending `DynamicObject` in the model assembly which proxies any requests for properties down to your anonymous type via reflection. It would be ugly, but I *think* it should work... effectively making the anonymous types public.

Comment: Ah yes I found that solution here: http://www.heartysoft.com/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic, except I don't believe output assembly's identity is consistent when it's being generated dynamically via the Razor Build Engine.

Comment: Yep - as I thought - outputting the Razor view's assembly qualified name shows that any change to the markup forces a recompile and also the assembly name changes.

Comment: have gone for something a little like that (added an answer); not a deep-proxying, just effectively cloning the public properties of the type into an Expando.  I considered doing it as dynamic delegates so as not to clone the reference; but ultimately for doing it with anonymous types that's just not needed.

Answer (score -1):

[ASP.NET MVC dynamic view sections](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/09/08/ASPNET-MVC-dynamic-view-sections.aspx)

How about this?