# Anonymous types object creation and passed into MVC# razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

Q1: What is better shorthand version of the following?
Q2: How can I pass anonymous types to my view in mvc3?

```
    public ViewResult Index3()
    {
        List<T1> ls = new List<T1>();
        ls.Add(new T1 { id = 1, title = "t1", val1 = 1, val2 = 2});
        ls.Add(new T1 {id=2, title="t2", val1=3, val2=4});
        ls.Add(new T1 { id = 3, title = "t3", val1 = 5, val2 = 6});

        return View(ls);
    }
```

(Q1)  Something similar to?:

```
        List<T1> ls = new List<T1>(
            List<T1>(new { id = 1, title = "t1", val1 = 1, val2 = 2}
            new { id = 2, title = "t2", val1 = 3, val2 = 4})
        );
```

(Q2)  Something similar to?:

```
    public ViewResult Index3()
    {                           
        return View(List(new { id = 1, title = "t1", val1 = 1, val2 = 2 }
            new { id = 2, title = "t2", val2 = 3, val2 = 4 }
        );
    }
```

Then reference the above in the razor view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Some Anonymous or Dynamic Model>

    @item.id
    @item.title
    @item.val1
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1 is a matter of preference.  There is no performance difference as the compiler internally creates similar code.

Q2 is impossible, you must create a non-anonymous type to be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Could use ViewBag to pass your list to the view.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend this. ViewBag should really only be used for something like the page Title or a Message and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

1. Collection initializers are written like this:

   ```
   List<T1> ls = new List<T1> {
       new T1 { id = 1, title = "t1", val1 = 1, val2 = 2 },
       new T1 { id = 2, title = "t2", val1 = 3, val2 = 4 },
       new T1 { id = 3, title = "t3", val1 = 5, val2 = 6 }
   };
   ```
2. Create an implicitly-typed array:

   ```
   return View(new [] { new { id = 1, ... }, ... });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Neither option will work as anonymous types are **internal** and razor views are compiled into a separate assembly.

See:
[Dynamic view of anonymous type missing member issue - MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429957/dynamic-view-of-anonymous-type-missing-member-issue-mvc3)